# mysql, tcp/ip, and passwords

Tags: passwords, mysql

I can't figure out why this is happening.

My user has two accounts:  `ans@localhost` for socket connections and `ans@%` for TCP/IP connections.  My host name is `valiant`.

```
mysql> select host,user,password from mysql.user where user = 'ans';
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user | password                                  |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | ans  | *40BA1B1CA7EE7B1B5FE4B2B754F74CD789DA6959 |
| %         | ans  |                                           |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Note that the `ans@%` account has no password.

```
$ mysql -uans -hvaliant
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 221
Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution
mysql>
```

I can log in without a password, which means I'm using my TCP/IP account, which I can verify with `\s` :

```
mysql> \s
Current user:           ans@valiant
Connection:             valiant via TCP/IP
```

So I assign a password to the account.

```
mysql> set password for 'ans'@'%' = password('foo');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> set password for 'ans'@'localhost' = password('foo');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select host,user,password from mysql.user where user = 'ans';
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user | password                                  |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | ans  | *F3A2A51A9B0F2BE2468926B4132313728C250DBF |
| %         | ans  | *F3A2A51A9B0F2BE2468926B4132313728C250DBF |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can log in through the local socket

```
$ mysql -uans -pfoo
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 233
Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution   
mysql>
```

but not over TCP/IP

```
$ mysql -uans -pfoo -hvaliant
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ans'@'valiant' (using password: YES)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Typical.  As soon as I ask a question, I stumble on the answer.

```
mysql> select host,user,password from mysql.user ;
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user | password                                  |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root | *64B2393C4607E57C549B41537134BC7C3314164E |
| localhost |      |                                           |
| valiant   |      |                                           |
| localhost | ans  | *F3A2A51A9B0F2BE2468926B4132313728C250DBF |
| %         | ans  | *F3A2A51A9B0F2BE2468926B4132313728C250DBF |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`mysql` helpfully (?) created two users with blank username and blank passwords, which allow any user to connect from that host without a password.

```
mysql> drop user ''@'valiant';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

$ mysql -uans -pfoo -hvaliant
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 249
Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution
```